# How to turn off eslint rule?

Tags: eslint, tslint, typescript-eslint

How do you turn off an eslint rule, for example no-inferrable-types which comes from the extension "eslint:recommended"?

For example if my .eslintrc.json contains:

```
"extends": [
    "eslint:recommended",
.....
"@typescript-eslint/no-inferrable-types": [
          "error",
          {
            "ignoreParameters": false,
            "ignoreProperties": false
          }
        ],
```

Comment: Please upvote this essential piece of information missing from google searches

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the value to "off" , as described here:
https://eslint.org/docs/latest/user-guide/configuring/rules

For example:

```
"@typescript-eslint/no-inferrable-types": "off",
```

Comment: Please upvote question and answer if helpful